# How to override the TextInput from React-Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin, textinput

**I only want to override the specific fields. Setting the custom theme will override the other fields too.**

**Tried using useStyles but didn't work and tried using direct style props but that also didn't work.**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    MuiInputBase: {
        root: {
            width: "800px"
        }
    }
});


<TextInput className={classes.MuiInputBase} variant="outlined" label="Search" source="search" alwaysOn />
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the docs, `className` only allows to override the style of the root component. To override the inner styles, you must use the `classes` prop:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    MuiInputBase: {
        root: {
            width: "800px"
        }
    }
});

const MyInput = () => {
   const classes = useStyles();
   return <TextInput classes={classes} variant="outlined" label="Search" source="search" alwaysOn />;
};
```

More details at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#overriding-a-component-style

Comment: How could this be done in a theme?